# Gzip decompression for incoming Gzip compressed request using server configuration for spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I am able to decompress the request using filter but I want some configuration or application parameters so to handle decompression of POST **requests**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat does not support request decompression. There is an [enhancement request](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62072) that may result in it being supported in the future. Your best option is to use a filter as you have been doing.